# I'm facing a heroku doployment problem, npm start not working

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment, npm-start

I need your help in some heroku stuff, I'm facing a problem, And my logs in heroku says: npm ERR! Failed at the blog@0.0.0 start script.
• I'm building an express NodeJS app.

Npm start fails, Any help please ?
Thank you so much !!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. It would be a lot more helpful to show us the _complete_ log, or at least the complete section with errors and warnings. Just "npm ERR! Failed at the blog@0.0.0 start script" doesn't tell us anything useful. Also, you say this is a deployment problem, but it sounds like a runtime issue? Where are you seeing this log output?

Answer (score 0):

Update in your `package.json` the file you are using for the server.

Under 'Scripts' :

```
'Scripts': 
    { "start": "filename where your server is hard coded" }
```